# htaccess redirect where index.php? exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've always found htaccess to be something a black art :)

I have a site powered by a CMS which had index.php in the url. My usual htaccess is standard enough to remove that.

However, historically, the site has a URL that's been offline http://domain.org/index.php?/resources/name-index/a/steven

However, this URL no longer exists and should instead point to http://domain.org/pages/steven

Alongside the other redirects I added

```
RewriteRule ^resources/name-index/a/steven http://domain.org/pages/steven
```

However, when I hit http://domain.org/index.php?/resources/name-index/a/steven we get a 404, however, if we hit http://domain.org/resources/name-index/a/steven it rewrites as you'd expect to the new page.

Can't help but think the existence of the ? in the url is wreaking havoc with the rule or the fact that index.php is being removed by another rule above (wouldn't have thought it would have mattered).

Suggestions welcomed.

Comment: same thing unfortunately

Comment: rewriterule by default only considers actual path components, e.g. `example.com/foo/bar/baz.php`, it'll only look at the `foo/bar/baz.php` component. if you want to look at the query string, you'd need to use a `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in the beginning of your htaccess (which should be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/resources/name-index/a/steven$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /pages/steven? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That works to a degree. It redirects to the right place but the url is now /pages/steven?/resources/name-index/a/steven

Comment: Sorry i forgot something. I edited my answer, should be working as expected now

Comment: Brilliant, thank you...where's the 'buy beer' button ?